# Fixed header with fixed alerts

Tags: html, css

If I have a website setup like a bootstrap fixed header:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

So the header has position:fixed and the body has padding-top:70px.

What's the most preferred method of adding a fixed alert under the fixed header so the body pushes down accordingly?

The best solution I can think of is using JQuery to add a modifying class to the body with padding-top:140px if there is a fixed alert up the top.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For making the alert notification fixed at the upper right side, you can modify the css e.g.

```
#success_alert, #error_alert{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  margin: 70px 10px 0px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Maybe you should, adjust the margin depends on your header height.
That works for me well.

Comment: Yeah cool, thanks mate. Adding a modifying class seems to be the things to do. Cheers!

Comment: @aldrien.h how can I have this same alerts but fixed in order to show them even if the user scrolls the page. Actually I have a `fixed` navbar so if I set the alerts to fixed to, it makes my navbar not to respond on clicks. How can I solve it? I'm using **materializecss**

Comment: I have solved this, I used `margin-top` with value equals to my navbar height so the alerts apear just after the navbar. And now it works like a charm, both my fixed navbar and my fixed alerts.